# field embeddings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm reading Algebraic Number Theory by Neukirch and unfortunately I have a weak background in field theory. In section 5, we consider an algebraic number field $K| \mathbb{Q} $ of degree n. This gives us a canonical mapping

$j:K \rightarrow K_\mathbb{C} := \prod _\tau \mathbb{C} ,$ where $a \mapsto ja=\tau a $

which comes from the $n$ different complex embeddings $\tau: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}.$

What exactly are the $n$ embeddings $\tau: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that this comes from writing $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ using the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Then the $n$ embeddings $\tau: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ correspond to the $n$ complex conjugates of $\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, so we just multiply an element of $K$ with a complex conjugate of $\alpha$?

Comment: @010110111, no, the notation $\tau a$ means $\tau(a)$, the application of $\tau$ to an element $a$. More precisely, each element in $K$ is a polynomial expression $p(\alpha)$; an embedding $\tau$ sends $p(\alpha)$ to $p(\beta)$, where $\beta$ is a  complex conjugate of $\alpha$.